# Directives are overwriting each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives, one checks the size of the file, while the other one ensures that the user is uploading a valid file format. They are both assigned to a `input=file` element, and seperate they work, but together, the validFileSize directive seems to cause the selectNgValidationFiles to not work.

```
//view

<input type="file" name="uploadedDocs" id="uploadedDocs" data-ng-model="fileStore.file" select-ng-validation-files valid-file-size multiple>

//controller

function validFileSize($parse){

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

            var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            var maxSize = 2000; //2000 B
            el.bind('change', function() {

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.fileStore.maxSizeError = false;
                    if (el[0].files.length > 1) {
                        modelSetter(scope, el[0].files);
                    } else {
                        modelSetter(scope, el[0].files[0]);
                    }

                    if(el[0].files.length > 0) {
                        var fileSize = el[0].files[0].size;
                        if (fileSize === 0) {
                           scope.fileStore.maxSizeError = true;
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
            });
        }

    }
}

function selectNgValidationFiles() { //if files to be uploaded vary in future, add condition to check type or create new directive
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
            var validFormats = ['pdf', 'PDF', 'doc', 'DOC', 'docx', 'DOCX', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG','png', 'PNG', 'gif', 'GIF', 'pptx', 'PPTX', 'csv', 'CSV', 'xlsx', 'XLSX', 'zip', 'ZIP'];
            elem.bind('change', function () {
                validFile(false);
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$render();
                });
            });
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                console.log('elem : ',elem)
                ngModel.$setViewValue(elem[0].files[0]);
            };
            function validFile(bool) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('pdfIncorrect', bool);
            }
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                var ext = value.name.substr(value.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
                if(ext=='') return;
                if(validFormats.indexOf(ext) == -1){
                    console.log('not valid format')
                    return value;
                }
                validFile(true);
                return value;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

**question**

What is causing my directives to break one another? I assume one is overwriting the other somehow but I can't work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not merge them into one directive or one service function?
Check file format first, if ok then proceed with file size check.

It's probably because you are now calling the $scope apply function twice (one in each directive), which generally does not work well.